# alias def []=(key, value) method in ruby

Tags: ruby

Normally to override a method I would just alias it:

```
 alias original_method_name method_name
```

I have now come across a method that looks like this:

```
def []=(key, value)
end
```

And I am not sure how to alias this one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe I didn't understand the question, but

```
>> class Hash
..   alias :foobar :[]=
..     end
=> nil
>> h = Hash.new
=> {}
>> h.foobar(:a, 1)
=> 1
>> h
=> {:a=>1}
```

Comment: Thanks this does the trick. I hadn't thought to assign it as a symbol :)

Comment: What does the colon square brackets notation do?  :[]=   <--- that.

Comment: `[]` and `[]=` are just normal methods. For arrays and hashes the former is used to get elements and the latter to set them. `a[1] = 'foo'` is syntactic sugar for `a.[]=(1, 'foo')`.

Answer (score 3):

alias accepts symbols as arguments, therefore, here is an example of what you want to do:

```
class Toto
  def initialize
    @t = {}
  end

  def []=(k,v)
    @t[k] = v
  end

  alias assign :[]=
end

t = Toto.new

t[1] = 5
t.assign(3, 4)

puts t.inspect
```

displays: `#<Toto:0x29b8318 @t={1=>5, 3=>4}>`

Also, you got the parameter order of alias wrong, it's `alias new_name old_name`

Comment: thanks, btw I always prefix the new method with original_ or something similar so I can tell what the original one was :)

Comment: i see, I thought you were referring to the original method name, not the other way round ;)